# What vector theorem should be used?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vectors

I have to integrate this line integral
$$\int_C \mathbf F \cdot d\mathbf r$$

Where $\mathbf F = (\frac{y}{x^2 + y^2},\frac{-x}{x^2 + y^2})$ and $C$ is the curve $x^2 + 2y^2 = 1$ oriented anticlockwise

Using parametrisation the answer is $-2\pi$ which is correct but does not use a vector theorem. I tried using green's theorem but the integral becomes $0$ after taking the necessary derivatives which comes from the discontinuity at the origin? Is there a way to apply greens theorem in this case, or is there another theorem that could be used? Thanks

Comment: On which domain do you want to apply Green's theorem? You cannot apply it to the interior of the ellipse since $F$ is not continous on it. 

You can apply Green's theorem to the domain $D$ bounded by the curve $C$ and the circle $C_2$ $x^2+y^2=2$ (for example), both with counterclockwise orientation. Since $curl(F)=0$ and the boundary of $D$ is $C_2\cup(-C)$, then $\int_{C}F\cdot d\vec{r}=\int_{C_2}F\cdot d\vec{r}$. The second integral is straightforward to compute using the standard parametrization of circles.

Comment: Green's theorem here is just used to tell you that any closed curve gives you the same value. So instead of using the ellipse, use the unit circle.

Comment: Note that ${\bf F}=-\nabla{\rm arg}$, so that the result $-2\pi$ is intuitively obvious.

Comment: Nameless could you elaborate on how Green's theorem tells you that any closed curve gives you the same value? And to Christian Blatter, what exactly is F=−∇arg?

Comment: Would I be able to apply greens theorem to a domain that does not contain the origin? The integral is $0$ even before picking a domain so how does that work?

Comment: To apply Green's theorem, a crucial condition is that $F=<P,Q>$ is of class $C^1$ (i.e. $P$ and $Q$ have continuous partial derivatives) on an open region containing $D$ and its boundary curve $C$. 

Since, in the interior of the ellipse, $F$ is not even continuous, you cannot apply Green's Theorem on this domain and the integral has no reaon to be $0$ (and is not $0$, as you computed it using parametrization).

Comment: @Bob, Note that if $C_2$ is any other closed curve containing your ellipse, then the line integral over $C_2$ and your ellipse is equal to the area bounded (without $0$ of course), which by Green's theorem are equal. Your partial derivatives are not well-defined over the region you want to integrate.